# Chart.js plot two graphs with different x/y values in same chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to plot two graphs of system responses in one single chart.
The problem is, that those graphs don't necessarily share the same x values with one of them having fewer x values than the other. It somehow looks like that the scaling of one x axis is off.

I tried creating two separate x axes but even if I extend the red graph to have the same min and max x value both axes are scaled differently (see how 560 & 570 are aligned).

This is what the graph should look like (made in MS Excel):
[image: this is what it should look like]

This is how far I get with Chart.js:
[image: this is what I get]

Here is the code I came up with:

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:60vh; width:40vw">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
const data = {
  datasets: [{
      label: 'IST',
      data: [0, 0.043, 0.693, 0.378, 0.065, 0.090, 0.108, 0.061, 0.038, 0.172, 1.000, 0.565, 0.049, 0.065, 0.036],
      borderColor: ['rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)'], //blue
      yAxisID: 'y1',
      xAxisID: 'x1',
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
    },
    {
      label: 'SOLL',
      data: [0, 0.02, 0.7, 0.04, 0.1, 0.04, 1, 0.04, 0.05, 0.04, 0.04],
      borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'], //red
      yAxisID: 'y2',
      xAxisID: 'x2',
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
    }
  ]
}

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index'
    },
    pointRadius: 0,
    scales: {
      y1: {
        min: 0
      },
      y2: {
        display: false,
        min: 0
      },
      x1: {
          labels: [350, 410, 435, 460, 485, 510, 535, 560, 585, 610, 645, 680, 705, 730, 760]
      },
      x2: {
        display: true,
        labels: [350, 410, 450, 490, 525, 570, 660, 690, 730, 750, 760]
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: You are using the default `type: "category"` axis. Thus, the labels are transformed to strings and positioned proportional to their *index*, not their value; each category has an equal space on the axis. If you want to use the *values* of the labels, you have to declare the [axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#common-options-to-all-axes) as `type: "linear"`. Also, it would be simpler if you added the x values to the data, e.g., `data: [{x: 350, y:0}, {x: 410, y: 0.02}, ...]`; that way you don't need to use two axes.